# How to merge values inside stateless component?

Tags: javascript

Updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it. How can I merge it? Function `addFruits` receives multiple objects like:

```
{fruitName: banana} {fruitName: apple} {fruitName: watermelon}
```

How to push this `fruitName`'s into fruits state?

My code returns only the last `fruitName`. But how to merge all `fruitName`s like `array.push(val)`;

```
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]); // this is the state

    function addFruits(value){
    Api.get(`${PATH.GET_SELECTED_FRUITS}/${value}/fruits`).then(res => { // this method gives me multiple object, (like {fruitName: banana} {fruitName: apple} {fruitName: watermelon})
        res.map(result => {
            setProps(result.fruitName); 
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the existing `fruits` array with the result from the API:

```
.then((res) => {
  setFruits([
    ...fruits,
    ...res.map(fruit => fruit.fruitName)
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the response with the state -

```
function addFruits(value){
    Api.get(`${PATH.GET_SELECTED_FRUITS}/${value}/fruits`).then(response => {
           totalFruits = [...fruits,
             ...response.map(fruit => fruit.fruitName)]
          setFruits(totalFruits);
        })
    })
```